# Vimeo thumbnail from private video

Tags: php, thumbnails, vimeo, vimeo-api

I have read over the API docs, but I am lost.

All I want to do is get the thumbnails from a private video.

I am not building an app, but to get the keys I need I have to include a site for the app, a logo and return url for the app.

Again I just need a thumbnail.

I am not new to API's, but I really need some example php code to get me started and what to do about setting up an app to get the keys I need.

From what I do understand I should use oembed which seems straight forward, but I need help with the authentication.

Answer (score 11):

### Create an [App](https://developer.vimeo.com/apps)

First thing is first, you need to create an application on the Vimeo developer website under your account. Don't worry too much about the site for the app, or a logo, and a return url for the application.

You could simply enter `localhost` for the website url and the return url and you could upload an image of yourself for the logo (notice the image is not required).

*I do however recommend filling in the "description" to best fit what you're trying to do.*

These three requirements are only for a specific authentication, which isn't required for what you want to do.

Just make sure you answer **NO** to the following questions:

> Will you charge users to utilize your app? 
>   Will your integration be ad supported?

And answer "Web Server" to the question:

> What platform(s) will be running this app?

There may be one point where they'll ask if your app needs **UPLOAD** access. Make sure you answer **NO**, as applications that request UPLOAD access go through a review.

### Creating the token

Go under your app's "**Authentication**" tab.

Basically, we're going to just skip the authentication that uses the callback url and just directly create a token with the following scopes:

**PUBLIC, PRIVATE**
[image: public private scopes vimeo token]
*Don't bother copying my token, I already deleted it.*

Once you create your token, make sure you copy it and store it server side somewhere. Once you refresh your page, you will be unable to get the token again. Notice, that you are only using PUBLIC, and PRIVATE scopes. Since you are only requesting information, this is enough.

Additionally, you need your **Client Identifier** and your **Client Secrets** that were given along under your App's authentication tab.

### Using the [Official Vimeo PHP LIbrary](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php)

**Basic authentication using client id, client secrets, and token.**

```
//Where $client_id and $client_secrets are variables with your vimeo client id 
//and secrets that you copied from the app you created on Vimeo.
$vimeoLib = new \Vimeo\Vimeo($client_id, $client_secrets);

//Where $token is the variable containing the token you generated earlier
$vimeoLib->setToken($token);
```

**Getting all thumbnails**

Vimeo will generate multiple thumbnails (at different sizes). If you don't know what your video's thumbnail Id is, then we'll have to go through all the video data first.

We'll first see how to get your thumbnails from all the data that is returned from a single video.

For this we'll be using this API:

```
GET https://api.vimeo.com/videos/{video_id}
```

Which returns the following:

```
+------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Http Status Code | Explanation                                      |
+------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| 200 Ok           |                                                  |
+------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| 404 not found    | If the video cannot be found.                    |
+------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
```

Just make sure you know what your vimeo id is.

```
//Where $vimeo_id is a variable containing your video's vimeo Id
$response = $vimeoLib->request("/me/videos/".$vimeo_id);
```

The response with the thumbnails will look something like this:

```
{
    //I've replaced information regarding my videos with {SOME_DESCRIPTIVE_TEXT}
    //More info here
    "pictures": {
            "uri": "/videos/{VIMEO_ID_HERE}/pictures/{THUMBNAIL_ID_HERE}",
            "active": true,
            "type": "custom",
            "sizes": [
                {
                    "width": 100,
                    "height": 75,
                    "link": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/{THUMBNAIL_ID_HERE}_100x75.jpg?r=pad",
                    "link_with_play_button": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F{THUMBNAIL_ID_HERE}_100x75.jpg&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png"
                },
                {
                    "width": 200,
                    "height": 150,
                    "link": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/{THUMBNAIL_ID_HERE}_200x150.jpg?r=pad",
                    "link_with_play_button": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F{THUMBNAIL_ID_HERE}_200x150.jpg&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png"
                },
                {
                    "width": 295,
                    "height": 166,
                    "link": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/{THUMBNAIL_ID_HERE}_295x166.jpg?r=pad",
                    "link_with_play_button": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F{THUMBNAIL_ID_HERE}_295x166.jpg&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png"
                },
                {
                    "width": 640,
                    "height": 360,
                    "link": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/{THUMBNAIL_ID_HERE}_640x360.jpg?r=pad",
                    "link_with_play_button": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F{THUMBNAIL_ID_HERE}_640x360.jpg&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png"
                },
                {
                    "width": 960,
                    "height": 540,
                    "link": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/{THUMBNAIL_ID_HERE}_960x540.jpg?r=pad",
                    "link_with_play_button": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F{THUMBNAIL_ID_HERE}_960x540.jpg&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png"
                },
                {
                    "width": 1920,
                    "height": 1080,
                    "link": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/{THUMBNAIL_ID_HERE}_1920x1080.jpg?r=pad",
                    "link_with_play_button": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F{THUMBNAIL_ID_HERE}_1920x1080.jpg&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png"
                }
            ],
            "resource_key": "{RESOURCE_KEY}"
        }
        //More info here
  }
```

To retrieve the information you're looking for, you need to do something like so:

```
//Check to see if the request didn't fail
if($response["status"] === 200){

  //Get the pictures object
  $thumbnailsObject = $response["body"]["data"]["pictures"];

  //Get the URI, so next time you can directly request the thumbnails instead of going through the whole video data
  $thumbnailUri = $thumbnailsObject["uri"];

  //Array of thumbnail links that'll be populated after loop.
  $thumbnails = [];
  //thumbnail without S
  foreach($thumbnailsObject["sizes"] as $thumbnailObject){
    $thumbnails[] = $thumbnailObject["link"];
  }

  //Done, do something with $thumbnails
}
```

**Request only thumbnails:**

Once you've gotten the URI, you can call your thumbnails in future requests like so:

```
GET https://api.vimeo.com/videos/{video_id}/pictures/{picture_id}

$response = $vimeoLib->request("/me/videos/".$vimeo_id."/pictures/".$picture_id);
```

or with the `$thumbnailUri` variable from before.

```
$response = $vimeoLib->request("/me".$thumbnailUri);
```

Answer (score 1):

I also have the same issue for my private video thumbnail. To get the private video thumbnail I downloaded the Vimeo [SDK](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/libraries) and used this functionality.

```
public function get_video_thumbnail_by_id($video_id, $thumbType = 'medium')
{
    try {
        if (empty($video_id)) {
            throw new Exception("Invalid video ID");
        }

        $response = $this->client->request("/me/videos/$video_id");

        if ($response["status"] === 200) {
            $response_pictures = $response["body"]["pictures"]['sizes'];

            switch ($thumbType) {
                case 'small':
                    $result = $response_pictures[2]['link'];
                    break;
                case 'medium':
                    $result = $response_pictures[3]['link'];
                    break;
                case 'large':
                    $result = $response_pictures[4]['link'];
                    break;
                default:
                    $result = $response_pictures[3]['link'];
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            $result = null;
        }

        return $result;
    } catch (VimeoUploadException $ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
```